# What is this javascript or networking monitoring tool?

Tags: javascript

I just found an interesting article on ajaxian.com.

the article is http://blog.dynatrace.com/2011/03/22/testing-and-optimizing-single-page-web-2-0ajax-applications-why-best-practices-alone-dont-work-any-more/

i wonder the name of the tool he is using.

Anyone knows its name?

P.S: Can I post a question like this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using **[dynaTrace AJAX edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/Default.aspx)** by the looks of it ( and it's also on dynaTrace's blog too ;) )

It's a pretty decent tool to use with older versions of Internet Explorer  for tasks such a page speed loading, DOM inspection, etc. I've used it in the past where I wasn't able to use **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)** and Firefox.

Comment: // Thanks! I think it is. I will confirm once I get my windows laptop tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> use tools such as YSlow, PageSpeed or
>   dynaTrace AJAX Edition

The answer for your question is in first paragraph of that article.

Comment: And the fact there is a comment on the bottom of the page too :o)

Comment: Neil knight // sorry guys...I think I was in rush.